# Python script to map one string to another string

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I have a file called file1.txt whose contents are like:

file1.txt

Python is a general-purpose, interpreted, interactive, object-oriented and high-level programming language. Python was developed by Guido van Rossum in the late eighties and early nineties at the National Research Institute for Mathematics and Computer Science in the Netherlands. Python is derived from many other languages, including ABC, Modula-3, C, C++, Algol-68, SmallTalk and Unix shell and other scripting languages. Python is copyrighted. Like Perl, Python source code is now available under the GNU General Public License (GPL).

I want to map a string for eg. the third sentence in the file to another string like -"Python was designed to be highly readable which uses English keywords frequently " .

How this mapping can be done in python? I got to know that dictionary is equivalent to hashmap in python but can dictionary be used to map 1 string to another??

I tried something like:

```
f=open("log5.txt")
dict = {'f.readline()': 'Python was designed to be highly readable which uses English keywords frequently'}
print(f.readline())
print(dict['f.readline()'])
```

But the above program maps the first sentence and also is there any better and efficient way to write the above program???

Answer (score 0):

Alright, 2 easy solutions: `.split(...)` and `re.(...)`

```
text = "Python is ... License (GPL)."

# add back the periods, this isn't the most efficient way (use regex or a tokenizer for better results but this works)
def add_periods(sentences)
   return [sentence + "." for sentence in periodless_sentences]

# i have no idea why you'd want to do this
def map_to_sentence_index(sentences):
   return {i: (s + ".") for (s, i) in enumerate(sentences)}

# split
periodless_sentences = str.split('. ')

# regex
import re
sentences = re.split(r' *[\.\?!][\'"\)\]]* *', text)
```

In python `map` means `map(func, lst)` where `func` is some function you want to apply to every element of `lst`. This is not what you are describing. `map` is a reserved keyword.

```
map(len, ["a", "bb", "ccc"]) => [1, 2, 3]
```

Honestly your question makes very little sense in the context of python and looks to be copy-pasted from a textbook. Please don't use stackoverflow as a homework solutions site. That said, here's the solution lol